# How to integrate inline-template with VueJS?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have little problem with display info with VueJS in inline template.
I have 1 component only with scripts
**Answer.vue**

```
<script>
export default {
    props: ['answer'],
    data(){
        return{
            editing: false
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I register in app.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
require('./bootstrap');
require('./fontawesome');

let app=createApp({})
app.component('user-info', require('./components/UserInfo.vue').default);
app.component('answer', require('./components/Answer.vue'));
app.mount("#app")
```

and i want to implement in answer.blade.php

```
<answer :answer="{{$answer}}">
    <div class="media post">
        @include ('shared._vote', [
            'model' => $answer
        ])
        <div class="media-body">
            {!! $answer->body_html !!}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <div class="ml-auto">
                        @can('update',$answer)
                        <a href="{{ route('questions.answers.edit', [$question->id,$answer->id,]) }}" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info">Edit</a>
                        @endcan
                        @can('delete', $answer)
                        <form method="POST" class="form-delete" action="{{route("questions.answers.destroy", [$question->id,$answer->id])}}">
                            @method('DELETE')
                            @csrf
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Remove</button>
                        </form>
                     @endcan
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
    
                </div>
                <div class="col-4">
                  
                    <user-info :model="{{$answer}}" label="Answered"></user-info>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
</answer>
```

and i get this in console and this is answers which i cannot see:
https://prnt.sc/wof0gh

Thanks for help :)

Comment: `Answer.vue` here `<template><slot></slot></template>` is missing

Comment: Okey but still didnt display answers.

Comment: error gone ? right for display you need to debug your self

Comment: Nope still the same https://prnt.sc/wohvge

Comment: I found solution .. After importing the component with import Answer from './components/Answer' and app.component('answer', Answer);  everything works fine for now :) Thanks for the help